# Rails ActionController::UnknownAction for favicon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, favicon

I have following line in my  app/views/layouts/application.html.erb

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

This somehow causes following error message int he logs and the favicon is not loaded. This happens only for certain paths not for the whole application.

```
ActionController::UnknownAction (No action responded to images. Actions:
```

How to get rid of it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe me.. try prefixing images with a slash and this should work

```
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

Comment: I will try and let you know, if it is fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `favicon_link_tag` helper instead:

```
<%= favicon_link_tag "/favicon.ico" %>
```

Just make sure your `favicon.ico` file is in the public folder... and do not forget the forward slash.